# Castle Windsor apply interceptors with selector after component is already registered

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, aop, interceptor

I have an abstract base class which contains several methods, of which one I need to intercept at all times. The base class can be inherited by user defined classes and registered with the container on application startup. In the event user hasn't registered one, the container installer will register one itself.

Here's the problem - the user should not have to worry about adding the interceptor. Container should add it on its own, regardless of who and where registered the component.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
if(!container.Kernel.HasComponent(typeof(MyBaseComponent)))
    container.Register(Component.For<MyComponent>()
        .Interceptors(InterceptorReference
        .ForType<MyComponentMethodInterceptor>())
        .SelectedWith(new MyComponentMethodSelector()).AtIndex(1));
```

`MyComponentMethodSelector` is a simple IInterceptorSelector which checks whether the methodname equals the one I need to intercept (in which case a `MyComponentMethodInterceptor` gets added to it).

As you can see it will check whether the component is already registered first.

The question is - do I have a way of adding an interceptor if it IS already registered? The most obvious choice that comes to mind is using an `IContributeComponentModelConstruction`, however at that point I will run into not being able to select the method which the interceptor gets added to. Or is there?

**EDIT:**

I should have been a little more specific. I need to add an interceptor for a specific method only. Hence why I'm using a MyComponentMethodSelector. I am aware of IContributeComponentModel, and I started out with that until I realised there was no way for me to add a method selector.

Comment: NeroS, did you have any chance to find how to handle what you wanted, I'd be interested to hear about it

Comment: I have not unfortunately. I got reassigned to a different project so this one is currently on hold. I will get back to it at one point though.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily add configuration to a component with a ComponentModel construction contributor that is called at the construction of the component model for your service by implementing [`IContributeComponentModelConstruction`](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.ComponentModel-construction-contributors.ashx).

Let's say you want to add an interceptor to any implementation of `IEventuallyRegistered`, and if the user didn't register a custom component you want to use `DefaultRegistration`:

```
public interface IEventuallyRegistered { void test(); }
public class DefaultRegistration : IEventuallyRegistered { public void test() { } }
public class EventuallyRegisteredInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) { invocation.Proceed(); }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<EventuallyRegisteredInterceptor>());
        container.Register(Component.For<IEventuallyRegistered>().ImplementedBy<DefaultRegistration>());
        // I'm not doing the optional registration, I just want to 
        // demonstrate upgrading a additional configuration

        var t = container.Resolve<IEventuallyRegistered>();
        t.test();
    }
}
```

Implementing the `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` interface lets you change the configuration of the component model when it is created:

```
public class RequireInterception : IContributeComponentModelConstruction
{
    public void ProcessModel(IKernel kernel, ComponentModel model)
    {
        if (model.Services.Contains(typeof(IEventuallyRegistered)))
        {
            model.Interceptors.Add(new InterceptorReference(typeof(EventuallyRegisteredInterceptor)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the component to the container *before* registering your component:

```
container.Kernel.ComponentModelBuilder.AddContributor(new RequireInterception());
container.Register(Component.For<IEventuallyRegistered>().ImplementedBy<DefaultRegistration>());
```

---

Even though it is possible to do it through the `ComponentRegistered` event of the kernel with a facility, **this is not recommended**; since it was included in the original answer I'm including it but I'm pushing it down. You would start by creating a facility

```
public class InterceptionFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        Kernel.ComponentRegistered += new Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentDataDelegate(Kernel_ComponentRegistration);
    }

    void Kernel_ComponentRegistration(string key, Castle.MicroKernel.IHandler handler)
    {
        if (typeof(IEventuallyRegistered).IsAssignableFrom(handler.ComponentModel.Implementation))
        {
            handler.ComponentModel.Interceptors.Add(new InterceptorReference(typeof(EventuallyRegisteredInterceptor)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then add the facility to the container *before* the registration of your component, or your facility will miss the event when registering your component:

```
container.AddFacility<InterceptionFacility>();
container.Register(Component.For<IEventuallyRegistered>().ImplementedBy<DefaultRegistration>());
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest the `IContributeComponentModelConstruction` solution. Kernel events aren't meant for modifying the `ComponentModel`

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic I edited the answer to push the recommended practice up

Comment: This seems promising on a quick look, I will try it out and if it works for this, I will mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I spoke too soon. That was what I, too, tried at start, until I realised I didn't have a way of applying it to a specific method only. I am currently checking the method name in the Intercept method itself, but this adds overhead that and looks like a very nasty hack. I would much prefer to be able to apply it to one method, rather than everything.

Comment: From what I've tried it should be possible if you are ready to delve into the details of the dynamic proxy that underlies the interception mechanism (you can examine a configured model vs a unconfigured one in the IContributeComponentModelConstruction) but as much as I try to gain knowledge on Castle, @KrzysztofKozmic may have a quicker answer for you

Comment: `IProxyGenerationHook` is what you're after. http://kozmic.net/2009/01/17/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial-part-iii-selecting-which-methods-to/ you can set it via `var options = model.ObtainProxyOptions(); options.Hook = hook;`

Comment: I'm pretty comfortable doing advanced stuff, I'll check out that blog entry and see how it would integrate with my functionality.

Comment: Is there any way to use an `IInterceptorSelector` with this method?

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic just read your comment - seems like `IInterceptorSelector` and `IProxyGenerationHook` have some overlapping functionality?

Comment: FYI: ObtainProxyOptions is an extension method defined in [ProxyOptionsUtil](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Proxy/ProxyOptionsUtil.cs), so you need to add a using statement for Castle.MicroKernel.Proxy to see it on ComponentModel.

Comment: @KrzysztofKozmic `options.Hook` expects an instance of `IReference` -- how does one construct that for Windsor? That is, how is the `hook` variable you reference in your comment created?